# Factorization of trivariate joint distribution under independence

Tags: probability

I know that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then we have $P(X,Y)=P(X)P(Y)$. Does the independence statement also imply any type of factorization of the trivariate joint $P(X,Y,Z)$?

Comment: Wondering if the bivariate independence statement alone (no other independencies) says anything about the factorization of the trivariate joint

Comment: You can apply the bivariate independance statement recursively if you want to generalize it. It can give you different conditions which enable you to factorize (if you have $(X_i)_{i \in [1,n]}$ and $\forall i \in [1,n], X_i$ is independant from $(X_{i-1}, .., X_1)$, then $P(X_1,..,X_n)=P(X_1)\cdot..\cdot P(X_n)$

Comment: @Vincent The three conditions that X is independent from Y, that Y is independent from Z and that Z is independent from X, together do not imply that the distribution of (X,Y,Z) is the product you say. In fact the fact that the assertion in your comment is false might be the single thing one stresses out the most in lectures on the subject. I find slightly worrying that you are sending the OP head first into **the** trap about the notion of stochastic independence. Or is it a kind of social experiment?

Answer (score 0):

You can find random variables $X, Y, Z$ such that every pair of variables is independent, yet the trivariate joint does not factorize in any way.

Continuous example: Divide up the unit cube into eight congruent subcubes of side length $1/2$. Select four of these cubes: Subcube #1 has one vertex at $(x,y,z)=(1,0,0)$, subcube #2 has one vertex at $(0,0,1)$, subcube #3 has one vertex at $(0,1,0)$, and subcube #4 has one vertex at $(1,1,1)$.  Now let $(X,Y,Z)$ be uniform over these four cubes. Then every pair of variables $(X,Y)$, $(X,Z)$, $(Y,Z)$ is uniform over the unit square (and hence independent), but the joint cannot be factorized.